# How to query multiple columns based on columns from another table

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables

TableOne

```
ID  EMPNAME1 EMPNAME2 EMPNAME3   
-----------------------------     
55  A        B        C            
56  B        C        D
```

TableTwo

```
EMPID   EMPNAME
----------------
 1      A  
 2      B
 3      C
 4      D
```

And I want my result set to look like this

```
ID   EMPID1   EMPID2   EMPID3
---------------------------------
55   1        2        3
56   2        3        4
```

Is there a query to do that?
I only know how to fetch data from another table for one column only using left join, but I am not sure how to do it for multiple columns.

Comment: Please provide a tailored toy database (e.g. using `.dump`). Please explain the logic behind your expected result in more detail. Please show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add more `JOIN`s based on your condition, will return the expected result as below:

```
 SELECT MT.ID, 
        A1.EMPID AS EMPID1, 
        A2.EMPID AS EMPID2, 
        A3.EMPID AS EMPID3
 FROM TableOne MT
 JOIN TableTwo A1 ON A1.EMPNAME = MT.EMPNAME1
 JOIN TableTwo A2 ON A2.EMPNAME = MT.EMPNAME2
 JOIN TableTwo A3 ON A3.EMPNAME = MT.EMPNAME3
```

Comment: Please help to fight the misundertanding that StackOverflow is a free coding service, by adding some explanation to this (almost) code-only answer.

Comment: Oh i see, all you have to do is add more joins and set the column you want to join...thanks will accept your answer when SO allows me too